# Keep app running front do not allow close app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

For a retail app where you want to show the app but do not allow customers to manipulate the phone in the shop.

**How can I keep the app oppened and avoid to be closed ?**
Maybe could be closed if I press certain key, but not from regular customers.

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices

Answer (score 0):

Use Google **Lock task mode**

here is the documentation link for lock task mode.

https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode

Comment: "Only apps that have been allowlisted by a device policy controller (DPC) can run when the system is in lock task mode" - How to do it, not depending on the Google ? Not even allowing google playstore in the system, just installing via apk.  BTW -> Thanks for your input!